# Change status and upload avatar in XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat

I'm a new XMPP member. I'm developing a iOS chat project. I learned the way to get online buddy, send and receive message :D, very happy.

But today, I'm researching changing my avatar and status and I don't know where I should begin. Hope receive your helps :) Thanks so much !!!!

Comment: hi, have u implemented the v-card feature. because i need ur help for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use vcard to implement the avatars in your app. Please visit the below URL for vcard based avatars:

**XEP-0153: vCard-Based Avatars**
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html

To change the status you have to send presence stanze with status you want to update.

Comment: hey bro can u help me with v-Card or avatars. because i m stuck in it